# Bar plot is plotting negative x-values in array, despite no negative values in array

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm getting this bug where, when plotting two arrays, I have negative x-values, despite there not being any negative values in my x-axis array. My x-axis should range from my minimum 0.005 to my max 0.995. There shouldn't be any values defined outside this range. Why am I getting I'm not sure why this is happening?

```
print(xValsAppx)
print()
print(probabilityX)

plt.bar(xValsAppx, probabilityX)
plt.xlabel('Sample')
plt.ylabel('Probability of Observing the Sample')
plt.title('Normal Distribution for a = 0, b = 1')
```

where xValsAppx is

```
[0.005 0.015 0.025 0.035 0.045 0.055 0.065 0.075 0.085 0.095 0.105 0.115
0.125 0.135 0.145 0.155 0.165 0.175 0.185 0.195 0.205 0.215 0.225 0.235
0.245 0.255 0.265 0.275 0.285 0.295 0.305 0.315 0.325 0.335 0.345 0.355
0.365 0.375 0.385 0.395 0.405 0.415 0.425 0.435 0.445 0.455 0.465 0.475
0.485 0.495 0.505 0.515 0.525 0.535 0.545 0.555 0.565 0.575 0.585 0.595
0.605 0.615 0.625 0.635 0.645 0.655 0.665 0.675 0.685 0.695 0.705 0.715
0.725 0.735 0.745 0.755 0.765 0.775 0.785 0.795 0.805 0.815 0.825 0.835
0.845 0.855 0.865 0.875 0.885 0.895 0.905 0.915 0.925 0.935 0.945 0.955
0.965 0.975 0.985 0.995]
```

and probabilityX is

```
[0.00977, 0.00995, 0.00999, 0.0, 0.00966, 0.01022, 0.01027, 0.01023, 0.0, 
0.01046, 0.01008, 0.0, 0.00967, 0.0096, 0.0102, 0.01008, 0.00977, 0.0, 
0.00961, 0.01003, 0.0095, 0.00944, 0.0106, 0.0, 0.0099, 0.0097,
0.01001,0.01017, 0.01014, 0.00977, 0.00998, 0.01013, 0.00978, 0.01017,
0.00939, 0.0, 0.00965, 0.0099, 0.01, 0.00973, 0.01009, 0.00968, 0.01003,
0.01009, 0.01022, 0.01022, 0.01022, 0.0, 0.01013, 0.00997, 0.00938, 0.0103,
0.00998, 0.00966, 0.01034, 0.00989, 0.0094, 0.0, 0.01071, 0.01065, 0.00945,
0.0098, 0.00997, 0.01, 0.0099, 0.01002, 0.00945, 0.00974, 0.01028, 0.01013,
0.01041, 0.00997, 0.01049, 0.0094, 0.00991, 0.00997, 0.01036, 0.01036,
0.00994, 0.01024, 0.01044, 0.01068, 0.00992, 0.0, 0.00996, 0.00955, 0.01014,
0.00991, 0.00977, 0.01013, 0.00989, 0.01027, 0.01037, 0.01016, 0.00957,
0.01001, 0.01004, 0.01054, 0.00946, 0.01005]
```

Image here:

[image]

Comment: please put you code as text, rather than as a figure.

Comment: please share your minimal code as well as your data too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), the default width of the bars is `0.8`, which doesn't fit to your x values. Try e.g `0.008` or `0.01`.

```
plt.bar(xValsAppx, probabilityX, 0.008)
```